# Internet explorer proxy does not follow exceptions after reboot

Tags: windows-7, networking, proxy, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

After a reboot any proxy exceptions are ignored by Internet explorer 11.
I can go to the list, add an ";" at the end and apply and everything will work as excpected. After a reboot the same behaviour applies again. (any and all changes

The exception list inludes an ip range with wildcards, and a couple of hostnames.
This behaviour is ocurring with multiple workstation.

I have checked and disabled any and all GPO's having anything to do with proxy settings, even then manually setting up the proxy and the exception list, the same behaviour happens.

All other applications using the system proxy settings have no issues whatsoever

Does anyone have an idea how I could narrow down the search why this is happening

Comment: It seems only hostnames are checked against the proxy exception list by Internet explorer [KB](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/262981) . Even so with ocal hostnames the same problem occurs. I will see if the problem persists using FQDN. According to KB both local and FQDN should work

Comment: Even FQDN's are going to the proxy, I have no idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is modifying the proxy exception order per MS help article ID: 3119660

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3119660/-this-page-cannot-be-displayed-error-when-you-use-proxy-exceptions-in

Comment: Consider adding some quoted reference to this answer supporting what you state in case the link ever dies so the answer content (i.e. actual instruction) is still available that is currently only available via that link per your suggestion.